# How to save and retrieve session from Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, session-state

I am trying to integrate Redis sessions into my authentication system written in Node.js.

I have been able to successfully set up Redis server, `connect-redis` and Express server.

Here is my setup (just the important bit):

```
var express = require("express");
var RedisStore = require("connect-redis")(express);
var redis = require("redis").createClient();

app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
    secret: "thisismysecretkey",
    store: new RedisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: redis })
}));
```

Now... How do I actually create, read and destroy the session? I am aware that that is probably extremely simple. I have read tons of articles on how to setup `connect-redis` and many questions here on SO, but I swear each one stops on just the configuration and does not explain how to actually use it...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That should be all there is to it.  You access the session in your route handlers via `req.session`.  The sessions are created, saved, and destroyed automatically.

If you need to manually create a new session for a user, call `req.session.regenerate()`.

If you need to save it manually, you can call `req.session.save()`.

If you need to destroy it manually, you can call `req.session.destroy()`.

See [the Connect documentation](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html) for the full list of methods and properties.

Answer (score 11):

Consider this code.

```
var express = require('express');
var redis   = require("redis");
var session = require('express-session');
var redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var client  = redis.createClient();
var app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use(session({
    secret: 'ssshhhhh',
    // create new redis store.
    store: new redisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: client,ttl :  260}),
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/',function(req,res){  
    // create new session object.
    if(req.session.key) {
        // if email key is sent redirect.
        res.redirect('/admin');
    } else {
        // else go to home page.
        res.render('index.html');
    }
});

app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    // when user login set the key to redis.
    req.session.key=req.body.email;
    res.end('done');
});

app.get('/logout',function(req,res){
    req.session.destroy(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("App Started on PORT 3000");
});
```

So you need to install **connect-redis** and pass your **express-session**  instance to it.

Then in middleware initialize redisStore with server details like this.

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'ssshhhhh',
    // create new redis store.
    store: new redisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: client,ttl :  260}),
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false
}));
```

I put ttl to 260, you can increase. After TTL reaches its limits, it will automatically delete the redis key.

In routers you can use req.session variable to SET, EDIT or DESTROY the session.

One more thing...

If you want custom cookie i.e not as same as in your Redis store you can use **cookie-parser** to set cookie secrets.

Hope it helps.

link : https://codeforgeek.com/2015/07/using-redis-to-handle-session-in-node-js/

Comment: Why do I keep seeing "create new session object" commented?  Does it mean to run `req.session.regenerate()`?  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Redis monitor tool to see all the action in real time!  When you refresh your app you will see the data appear in the console window.

```
redis-cli monitor
```

Sample Output for Sessions using tj/connect-redis

```
1538704759.924701 [0 unix:/tmp/redis.sock] "expire" "sess:F9x-YgbgXu1g7RG8tFlkwY3RV0JzHgCh" "3600"
1538704759.131285 [0 unix:/tmp/redis.sock] "get" "sess:F9x-YgbgXu1g7RG8tFlkwY3RV0JzHgCh"
1538704787.179318 [0 unix:/tmp/redis.sock] "set" "sess:Hl3LPbOBdKO44SG4zQHFn2gfdiWTwzWW" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":3600000,\"expires\":\"2018-10-05T02:59:47.178Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"domain\":\".indospace.io\",\"path\":\"/\"},\"path\":\"/\",\"userAgent\":{\"family\":\"NewRelicPingerBot\",\"major\":\"1\",\"minor\":\"0\",\"patch\":\"0\",\"device\":{\"family\":\"Other\",\"major\":\"0\",\"minor\":\"0\",\"patch\":\"0\"},\"os\":{\"family\":\"Other\",\"major\":\"0\",\"minor\":\"0\",\"patch\":\"0\"}},\"ip\":\"184.73.237.85\",\"page_not_found_count\":0,\"city\":\"Ashburn\",\"state\":\"VA\",\"city_state\":\"Ashburn, VA\",\"zip\":\"20149\",\"latitude\":39.0481,\"longitude\":-77.4728,\"country\":\"US\"}" "EX" "3599"
1538704787.179318 [0 unix:/tmp/redis.sock] "set" "sess:Hl3LPbOBdKO44SG4zQHFn2gfdiWTwzWW" "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":3600000,\"expires\":\"2018-10-05T02:59:47.178Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"domain\":\".indospace.io\",\"path\":\"/\"},\"path\":\"/\",\"userAgent\":{\"family\":\"NewRelicPingerBot\",\"major\":\"1\",\"minor\":\"0\",\"patch\":\"0\",\"device\":{\"family\":\"Other\",\"major\":\"0\",\"minor\":\"0\",\"patch\":\"0\"},\"os\":{\"family\":\"Other\",\"major\":\"0\",\"minor\":\"0\",\"patch\":\"0\"}},\"ip\":\"184.73.237.85\",\"page_not_found_count\":0,\"city\":\"Ashburn\",\"state\":\"VA\",\"city_state\":\"Ashburn, VA\",\"zip\":\"20149\",\"latitude\":39.0481,\"longitude\":-77.4728,\"country\":\"US\"}" "EX" "3599"
```

Comment: How to access this inside express? I want to list all the active session and delete user session manually as and when required.