# req.session.isAuthenticated isn't working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript, express

I've been working on a React app (localhost:3000) that uses an external API (localhost:8000). I tried to implement a session-based authentication system using express-session. When I log in, req.session.isAuthenticated is true. However, after a redirect or a refresh, the isAuthenticated field totally disappear from the session object.

Here's my Axios config for the React app:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080/',
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
  }
})
```

Here's my `express-session` and CORS config:

```js
app.use(
  session({
    name: 'admin',
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: false, maxAge: 3600 * 24 }
  })
)
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true
}))
```

Here's my requireAuth middleware:

```js
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'

export const RequireAdminAuth = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  if (req.session.isAuthenticated === true) {
    next()
  } else {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized', authenticated: false })
  }
}
```

Here's my login controller:

```js
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'
import * as fs from 'fs'
import { AdminUsername } from '../config/config'

const filePath = 'path/to/password.txt'
const correctPassword: string = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8').trim()

export const verifyPassword = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  if (req.body.password === correctPassword && req.body.username === AdminUsername) {
    req.session.isAuthenticated = true
    console.log(req.session, 'middleware')
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Authorized', authenticated: req.session.isAuthenticated })
    next()
  } else {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized', authenticated: false })
  }
}
```

Here's my admin router:

```js
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express'
import { verifyPassword } from '../middlewares/admin.middleware'
const router = express.Router()

router.post('/', verifyPassword)
router.get('/status', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  console.log(req.session, 'route')
  return res.json(req.session.isAuthenticated)
})
export default router
```

Comment: Add the script which includes the order you put it all together in.

Comment: Have a look at this question, it should solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26532987/23158885