# Share sessions with redis and passport on a subdomain?

Tags: node.js, session, redis, passport.js

I am using npm subdomain, inside my app I have routes that fake a subdomain

```
// looks like app.localhost:3000
router.get('/subdomain/app', app.dashboard);
```

So I have a login page on a subdomain and a login page on a non subdomain page. They don't share sessions, so I have to login twice. I want to setup redis, but I don't know how.

```
// here is my session middleware, I tried using .localhost
app.use(session({ secret: 'something', domain: '.localhost', }));
```

I have seen where people are using redis like

```
app.use(express.session({
    store:new RedisStore({
        host: config.redis.session.host,
        port: config.redis.session.port,
        db: config.redis.session.db
    }),
    secret: config.session_secret
}));
```

This seems like it could solve my issue but I have no clue how to setup a redisStore and where the config data comes from?

Can someone explain to me how to use redis so that when a user logs in on either app.example.io or example.io that he/she is logged in for good, no need to log in twice?

Answer (score 0):

You need to require following modules.

```
connect-redis
express-session
cookie-parser
```

Then use the following sample code:

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: "thisismysecretkey",
    store: new RedisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379})
}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)
})
```

Source : [How to save and retrieve session from Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014446/how-to-save-and-retrieve-session-from-redis)

Comment: Wow thanks this is helpful, I appreciate it. Let me implement it then I will check this!

Comment: When I try to log in it wont execute passport, it just does a POST and nothing happens?

Comment: I can login now, but the sessions are not shared??

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it, this is the most important piece - domain: **.yourdomain.io**  Make sure to have that preceeding dot before your domain.

```
var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  expressSession = require('express-session'),
  sessionMiddleware = null,
  redis = require('redis'),
  conn_redis = {
    path: '/var/run/redis/redis.sock',
    socket_keepalive: true
  }
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}))
const connectRedis = require('connect-redis')(expressSession),
  uid = require('uid-safe').sync
sessionMiddleware = expressSession({
  store: new connectRedis(conn_redis),
  secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  name: 'session_name',
  resave: false,
  rolling: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,    
  logErrors: true,
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    domain: '.yourdomain.io'
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
    maxAge: 3600000
  }
})
```